# Pylint recognizes an error, but code seems to work flawless (No value for argument 'value' in constructor call)

Tags: python, tkinter, pylint

I'm making a dropdown menu with Tkinter. It seems to be working just as expected, but Pylint in Visual Studio Code insists there is a problem in the following line:

```
drop = tk.OptionMenu(frame_products, clicked, *options)
```

The error message is `No value for argument 'value' in constructor call`.

Here is the rest of the function:

```
    parameter = entry_product.get()

    # Fetches all matches and stores in a list
    options = []
    for item in products:
        if parameter.lower() in item.name.lower() or parameter.lower() in item.ingredients.lower():
        name_and_ingredients = "(" + str(item.Id) + ") " + item.name + ": " + item.ingredients
        options.append(name_and_ingredients)
            
    # Set default value of drop down menu
    clicked = tk.StringVar()
    clicked.set(options[0])

    # Creates drop down menu
    drop = tk.OptionMenu(frame_products, clicked, *options)
    drop.grid(column=1, row=2)
```

Am I doing something wrong? If not, how do I make this error go away?

Comment: The third parameter is supposed to be the initial value of the OptionMenu.  It's being taken from the first element of `*options` instead, which seems perfectly valid to me - I guess pylint wants a *variable in the call to exactly line up with a *variable in the method's definition.

Comment: Is there a way to make the warning go away without changing my code?

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore the warning in the .pylintrc

```
[MESSAGES CONTROL]
disable=E1120
```

But i would also be interested in hearing a real solution.